# The library I'm using is causing issues on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, permissions, app-store

I have a live Flutter project running in app stores, and I'm encountering various unnecessary permission requests on iOS due to a library I'm using. To ensure that this library doesn't cause any issues on iOS, I'm working on two different branches. How can I make sure that the library works when building for Android while excluding it from the iOS build process?

I tried something in the pubspec.yaml file, but it didn't work.